# Loading multiple objects with the same function

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have to load few models and want to be able to reach them from outside the loader. As I try to follow the DRY rule, I want to create a single function for loading and returning the object.

```
function loadObject(obj, mtl) {
            var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
            return loader.load( obj, mtl, function ( object ) {
                return object;
            });
}
```

but after using in the main function

```
    var box = loadObject('box.obj', 'box.mtl');
    scene.add(box);
```

I get:

> THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.
>   undefined

Comment: Just guess here, but I think that the first argument of `loadObject` is not expecting a string 'box.obj', but some sort of object.

Comment: no. it should pass the string name to the loaders load function inside to fetch proper model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not `return`ing what you think you are from `loadObject`. The third parameter to `loader.load` is a callback; it's probably invoked asynchronously. `load` itself doesn't return anything, which is why `box` ends up being `undefined`. You should probably be passing what should happen when the load finishes into `loadObject`:

```
function loadObject(obj, mtl, onSuccess) {
    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
    loader.load(obj, mtl, onSuccess);
}

var box = loadObject('box.obj', 'box.mtl', function(box) {
    // 1
    scene.add(box);
});

// 2
more code
```

Keep in mind that with asynchronous methods with callbacks, the code underneath "2" could execute **before** the code under "1".

Comment: @mjanisz1: I wish I knew more about threejs, but alas I don't. You could ask that as a separate question though!